# No instances are allowed in the image heap for a class that is initialized or reinitialized at image runtime: sun.security.provider.NativePRNG

Tags: java, graalvm, quarkus

I am getting a very strange error while I am trying to compile to native.
Here is the error:

```
206853 [INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.nativeimage.NativeImagePhase] Running Quarkus native-image plugin on OpenJDK GraalVM CE 1.0.0-rc15
206863 [INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.nativeimage.NativeImagePhase] /opt/graalvm/bin/native-image -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Drx.unsafe-disable=true -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -jar example-project-api-services-1.0-runner.jar -J-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+PrintAnalysisCallTree -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https --enable-all-security-services -H:-SpawnIsolates -H:+JNI --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace
[example-project-api-services-1.0-runner:391]    classlist:  12,582.29 ms
[example-project-api-services-1.0-runner:391]        (cap):   1,021.83 ms
[example-project-api-services-1.0-runner:391]        setup:   2,121.29 ms
13:12:55,427 INFO  [org.hib.val.int.uti.Version] HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.0.Alpha4
13:12:55,729 INFO  [io.sma.fau.HystrixInitializer] ### Init Hystrix ###
13:12:55,731 INFO  [io.sma.fau.DefaultHystrixConcurrencyStrategy] ### Privilleged Thread Factory used ###
13:12:55,731 INFO  [io.sma.fau.HystrixInitializer] Hystrix concurrency strategy used: DefaultHystrixConcurrencyStrategy
13:12:55,737 WARN  [com.net.con.sou.URLConfigurationSource] No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
13:12:55,737 INFO  [com.net.con.sou.URLConfigurationSource] To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
13:12:55,761 INFO  [org.hib.Version] HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.2.Final}
13:12:55,774 INFO  [org.hib.ann.com.Version] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
13:12:55,799 INFO  [org.hib.dia.Dialect] HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
13:12:55,863 INFO  [io.sma.ope.api.OpenApiDocument] OpenAPI document initialized: io.smallrye.openapi.api.models.OpenAPIImpl@4878969e
13:12:57,347 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.0.0.Alpha4
13:12:58,200 INFO  [com.arj.ats.arjuna] ARJUNA012170: TransactionStatusManager started on port 38873 and host 127.0.0.1 with service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService
13:12:58,348 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO version 3.7.0.Final
13:12:58,440 INFO  [org.xni.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.7.0.Final
Warning: RecomputeFieldValue.ArrayIndexScale automatic substitution failed. The automatic substitution registration was attempted because a call to sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayIndexScale(Class) was detected in the static initializer of rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentCircularArrayQueue. Detailed failure reason(s): Could not determine the field where the value produced by the call to sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayIndexScale(Class) for the array index scale computation is stored. The call is not directly followed by a field store or by a sign extend node followed directly by a field store. 
Warning: RecomputeFieldValue.ArrayBaseOffset automatic substitution failed. The automatic substitution registration was attempted because a call to sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(Class) was detected in the static initializer of rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentCircularArrayQueue. Detailed failure reason(s): Could not determine the field where the value produced by the call to sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(Class) for the array base offset computation is stored. The call is not directly followed by a field store or by a sign extend node followed directly by a field store. 
Warning: RecomputeFieldValue.ArrayIndexScale automatic substitution failed. The automatic substitution registration was attempted because a call to sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayIndexScale(Class) was detected in the static initializer of rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscUnboundedArrayQueue. Detailed failure reason(s): Could not determine the field where the value produced by the call to sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayIndexScale(Class) for the array index scale computation is stored. The call is not directly followed by a field store or by a sign extend node followed directly by a field store. 
[example-project-api-services-1.0-runner:391]     analysis:  88,298.64 ms
Printing call tree to /builds/orema/example-project/services/example-project-services/example-project-api-services/target/reports/call_tree_example-project-api-services-1.0-runner_20190517_131435.txt
Printing list of used classes to /builds/orema/example-project/services/example-project-services/example-project-api-services/target/reports/used_classes_example-project-api-services-1.0-runner_20190517_131441.txt
Printing list of used packages to /builds/orema/example-project/services/example-project-services/example-project-api-services/target/reports/used_packages_example-project-api-services-1.0-runner_20190517_131441.txt
Error: No instances are allowed in the image heap for a class that is initialized or reinitialized at image runtime: sun.security.provider.NativePRNG
Detailed message:
Trace:  object java.security.SecureRandom
    method net.example-project.domain.collection.control.CollectionNumber.generate()
Call path from entry point to net.example-project.domain.collection.control.CollectionNumber.generate(): 
    at net.example-project.domain.collection.control.CollectionNumber.generate(CollectionNumber.java:24)
    at net.example-project.domain.collection.control.CollectionNumber_ClientProxy.generate(Unknown Source)
    at net.example-project.domain.collection.boundary.CollectionCreationContext.create(CollectionCreationContext.java:41)
    at net.example-project.domain.collection.boundary.CollectionCreationContext_Subclass.create$$superaccessor27(Unknown Source)
    at net.example-project.domain.collection.boundary.CollectionCreationContext_Subclass$$function$$51.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink$$Lambda$425/239200789.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at io.smallrye.restclient.async.AsyncInvocationInterceptorHandler$Decorator.lambda$decorate$0(AsyncInvocationInterceptorHandler.java:48)
    at io.smallrye.restclient.async.AsyncInvocationInterceptorHandler$Decorator$$Lambda$559/661106985.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:473)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- WARNING: The above stack trace is not a real stack trace, it is a theoretical call tree---
-- If an interface has multiple implementations SVM will just display one potential call  ---
-- path to the interface. This is often meaningless, and what you actually need to know is---
-- the path to the constructor of the object that implements this interface.              ---
-- Quarkus has attempted to generate a more meaningful call flow analysis below          ---
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
Error: Image build request failed with exit 331740
```

I think this logs says much about the error:
`Error: No instances are allowed in the image heap for a class that is initialized or reinitialized at image runtime: sun.security.provider.NativePRNG`

I found some issues @ GraalVM's Github repo.
https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/712

I think I should do something with `Delay class initialization` at https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips

So, I wrote this piece of Java code:

```java
@BuildStep
public RuntimeInitializedClassBuildItem secureRandom() {
    return new RuntimeInitializedClassBuildItem("sun.security.provider.NativePRNG");
}
```

But it don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first, using `@BuildStep` only works during Quarkus augmentation phase: you need to be in an extension for it to work. It won't work in application code.

Second you need to delay the runtime initialization of the class holding the field so in your case, probably `CollectionNumber`?

So I would try to add:

```
<additionalBuildArgs>--delay-class-initialization-to-runtime=net.example-project.domain.collection.control.CollectionNumber</additionalBuildArgs>
```

to the Native image phase in your pom.xml.

Comment: I was looking for something like that in the maven plugin. Is there any docs about these maven properties?

Comment: Not at the moment. We need to publish the Maven site somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional build params for Quarkus native build by using Maven pom.xml like this (in 2021):

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
        <quarkus.native.additional-build-args>--initialize-at-run-time=org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG\\,org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.SOMETHING_ELSE --trace-object-instantiation=sun.security.provider.NativePRNG</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>
      </properties>
.....
```

You can try to specify the list of multiple Inner classes:

```
--initialize-at-run-time=org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG\$Default\,org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG\$NonceAndIV --trace-object-instantiation=sun.security.provider.NativePRNG
```